# LD_PRELOAD didn't load my library and no errors or warnings

Tags: linux, ld-preload

I want to use `LD_PRELOAD` to hook my library before target running in Oracle Linux 7.9.
`LD_PRELOAD` load my library failed in  first scenario, but success in second scenario and third scenario.
I have no idea to make `LD_PRELOAD` work in first scenario.

```
1
[test@k8s-node2 hook]$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libtest.so 
-rwsr-sr-x 1 test test2 501328 Jan 31 07:04 /usr/lib64/libtest.so
`[test@k8s-node2 hook]$ ls -l child`
-rwsr-sr-x 1 test test2 12848 Jan 31 16:08 child
[test@k8s-node2 hook]$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libtest.so ./child &
[test@k8s-node2 hook]$ pmap -X `pidof child` | grep libtest
[test@k8s-node2 hook]$

2
[test@k8s-node2 hook]$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libtest.so 
-rwsr-sr-x 1 test test 501328 Jan 31 07:04 /usr/lib64/libtest.so
`[test@k8s-node2 hook]$ ls -l child`
-rwsr-sr-x 1 test test 12848 Jan 31 16:08 child
[test@k8s-node2 hook]$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libtest.so ./child &
[test@k8s-node2 hook]$  pmap -X `pidof child` | grep libtest
7fded2929000 r-xp 00000000  fd:02 40593442     4    4   2          4         0    0      0 libtest.so
7fded292a000 ---p 00001000  fd:02 40593442  2044    0   0          0         0    0      0 libtest.so
7fded2b29000 r--p 00000000  fd:02 40593442     4    4   4          4         4    0      0 libtest.so
7fded2b2a000 rw-p 00001000  fd:02 40593442     4    4   4          4         4    0      0 libtest.so

3
bash-4.2# chmod u-s,g-s child; chmod u-s,g-s /usr/lib64/libtest.so 
bash-4.2# ls -l child 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 test test2 8544 Feb  1 05:51 child
bash-4.2# ls -l /usr/lib64/libtest.so 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 test test2 8048 Feb  1 05:55 /usr/lib64/libtest.so
bash-4.2# su - test
[test@k8s-node2 hook]$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libtest.so ./child &
[test@k8s-node2 hook]$ pmap -X `pidof child` | grep libtest
7f6df60c0000 r-xp 00000000  fd:02 40593442     4    4   2          4         0    0      0 libtest.so
7f6df60c1000 ---p 00001000  fd:02 40593442  2044    0   0          0         0    0      0 libtest.so
7f6df62c0000 r--p 00000000  fd:02 40593442     4    4   4          4         4    0      0 libtest.so
7f6df62c1000 rw-p 00001000  fd:02 40593442     4    4   4          4         4    0      0 libtest.so
```

child.cpp

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]) {
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++) {
        printf("child argv%d:%s\n",i, argv[i]);
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(envp[i] != NULL) {
        printf("child envp%d: %s\n", i, envp[i]);
        i++;
    }

    while(1) {
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```bash
g++ child.cpp -o child
```

test.cpp

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void myhello(void) {
    printf("hello world!");
}
```

```bash
g++ -fPIC -shared test.cpp -o libtest.so -ldl
```

I try success in 2 and 3, but failed in 1.

Comment: you never call `myhello`. What is `LD_PRELOAD` supposed to do?

Comment: This is just simple example, so I don't call myhello in child.
It just test whether LD_PRELOAD can load libtest.so in child or not.

Comment: As the `ld.so` manual page says: "_Using the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`,  unless  the  executable  is  being  run  in  secure-execution mode (see below), in
            which case this variable is ignored._"  It would be a gaping security hole if you were able to inject arbitrary code into a process running as another user.